# Determine optimal time interval between character transitions

Tags: algorithm, performance, unix, time, command-line

The following code will display a character from `characters`, check if there are still jobs in the background and repeat.

```
for {  
    for c in characters {
        printf("\r%s \r", c)
    }
    if not job_still_running {
        break
    }
}
```

The problem is characters will transition too fast. Adding something like `sleep(0.1)` after `printf` will allow us to appreciate the animation better.

Is it be possible to determine the time interval programmatically? and if so, is it a good idea and what information do I require from the system to calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the proper syntax in command-line scripts, but in Java I would do it like this. You only require a way to measure the current time.

```
long time;
long DELAY = 800;  // each character visible for 0.8 seconds
for c in characters {
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    printf("\r%s \r", c)
    Thread.sleep(time + DELAY - System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```